# How to run codecept scenarios in order?

Tags: testing, codeceptjs

I am using the following command to run test scenario.

```
npx codeceptjs run --steps --grep "A1|X2|A3"
```

I am looking for a way to run these tests in the same order given. For some reason, this is not guaranteed. Is there a flag that I can use to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific functionality in Codeceptjs.
You can run tests from a folder in a specific order by starting test names with numbers.
However, you should avoid the tests depending on each other.
It is not a good idea to make tests dependent on other tests.